# How do I fix this Java Loop Scanner

Tags: java

This is part of a code that I am running and when the code runs it lets me enter a number but will not let me move on, it will just continue to print "Enter a student's total quiz score : " even though i have entered a value less than the perfect quiz score help!

```
  while (perfectQuizScore > quizScore ) {
        System.out.print("Enter a student's total quiz score : ");
        quizScore = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine()); // 6
        if (quizScore > perfectQuizScore) {
            System.out.println("Invalid value! Score must not be greater than perfect score.");
        }
        else if (quizScore < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid value! Value must be greater than 0.");
        }

    }
```

OUTPUT:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxtzO.png)

REVERSING THE SIGNS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udShu.png)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly... you want to exit the loop when the supplied quiz score is *less than (or equal to)* the perfect score? If so, you just need to change the sign in your while loop conditional (it is currently checking *greater than*).

Before:
  `while (perfectQuizScore > quizScore ) {`

After:
  `while (perfectQuizScore < quizScore ) {`

Now this is assuming that you initially set `quizScore` to a huge value (if you initialize it to `0` then the conditional will evaluate to false before entering the loop). A better solution is probably to use a `do-while` loop.

```
int quizScore = 0;
do {
   System.out.print("Enter a student's total quiz score : ");
   quizScore = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine()); // 6
   if (quizScore > perfectQuizScore) {
      System.out.println("Invalid value! Score must not be greater than perfect score.");
   }
   else if (quizScore < 0) {
      System.out.println("Invalid value! Value must be greater than 0.");
   }
} while (perfectQuizScore < quizScore or quizScore < 0);
```

Although I would personally probably structure this differently, to avoid writing your "bad" conditions down twice:

```
int quizScore = 0;
while (True) {
   System.out.print("Enter a student's total quiz score : ");
   quizScore = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine()); // 6
   if (quizScore > perfectQuizScore) {
      System.out.println("Invalid value! Score must not be greater than perfect score.");
   }
   else if (quizScore < 0) {
      System.out.println("Invalid value! Value must be greater than 0.");
   }
   else {
      // good input, exit the loop with a break statement
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: here is the whole program https://pastebin.com/4fB61gdK

Comment: How do I convert it to while? cause i have to do while and do while

Comment: I've edited to give examples of both "while" and "do-while"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following is what you searching:

```java
    do {
      System.out.print("Enter a student's total quiz score : ");
      quizScore = scnr.nextInt();
      if (quizScore > perfectQuizScore) {
          System.out.println("Invalid value! Score must not be greater than perfect score.");
      }
      else if (quizScore <= 0) {
          System.out.println("Invalid value! Value must be greater than 0.");
      } else {
          break; // get out of the loop
      }
    } while ( quizScore <= 0 || quizScore > perfectQuizScore );
```

Do the check (`while`) after getting the first time, also change the checks to stay on the loop until the user write a valid value.

The `do {...}` will let the code inside run one time before the `while` checks.

Comment: THIS WORKS WHEN CONVERTING TO WHILE while ( quizScore <= 0 || quizScore > perfectQuizScore );